# Generar un Json simple con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

tengo una cuestión que implica `PHP`, mi archienemigo.

Quiero hacer una página web enlazada a una base de datos donde tienen categorías, platos, precios, etc.

Me gustaría poder obtener un `JSON` muy bien definido, que cada categoría contenta todos los platos, y cada plato contenga los alérgenos que le correspondan según la base de datos, ya que, se especifican cómo son. Pongo una imagen aclarativa de cómo sería dicha `database`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mostrado ya cómo se compone la base de datos, la consulta que hago para obtener todos los datos que necesito mostrar es esta:

```
SELECT category.name AS categoryname, plates.name AS platename, plates.specifications, plates.price FROM category JOIN plates ON category.id_category = plates.id_category WHERE category.allow = true AND plates.allow = true;
```

Lo único malo es que no me da un resultado con los alérgenos, pero es cuestión de ponerse a ello, que hasta ahora, no me he puesto.
La pregunta en cuestión es, esta información la saco en un archivo php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname   = "restaurante_la_cena_menu";

$conexion = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname)
or die("Ha sucesido un error inesperado en la conexión de la base de datos");

// generamos consulta
$sql = "SELECT category.name AS categoryname, plates.name AS platename, plates.specifications, plates.price FROM category JOIN plates ON category.id_category = plates.id_category WHERE category.allow = true AND plates.allow = true; ";
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die();

$menu = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $category = $row["categoryname"];
    $plate = $row["platename"];
    $specification = $row["specifications"];
    $price = $row["price"];

    $menu[] = array('category' => $category, 'plate' => $plate, 'specification' => $specification, 'price' => $price);
}

$conexion->close();

$json_string = json_encode($menu, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json_string;


?>
```

El cual me da lo que necesito, pero de forma que se podría colocar mejor, y eso ya no lo controlo, me gustaría obtener un JSON con una estructura más bien parecida a esta:

```
[{
    "category": "categoria 1",
    "content": [{
        "plate": "plato 1",
        "price": "8",
        "allergen": [
            "alergeno 1",
            "alergeno 2",
            "alergeno 3"
        ]
    }]
}]
]
```

¿Qué es lo que tendría que poner en el PHP para poder sacar la información estructurada correctamente por categorías y platos?, porque hasta ahora solamente me sale, tal y como viene en el código, estructurado por filas. Cada fila de la query obtengo un resultado dentro del JSON.

---

**EDIT**

He conseguido gracias a Daniel en los comentarios ordenar el Array de forma legible, y gracias a A. Cedano estoy algo más cerca del resultado que quiero. Pero aun así no es suficiente, necesito mejorar la query, pero ya es algo que no entiendo bien.

La consulta que tengo ahora es esta:

```
SELECT category.name AS categoryname, GROUP_CONCAT(plates.name, ' ', plates.price) AS platenames FROM category JOIN plates ON category.id_category = plates.id_category GROUP BY category.id_category;
```

Lo cual me saca un resultado como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no entiendo bien cómo tendría que hacer las agrupaciones. Y menos si quiero meter los alergénos de cada plato.
¿Cómo podría hacerlo bien?

---

**EDIT 2**

Tratando de hacer la propuesta de @Triby, me he topado con un error el cual no se reconocer cómo está cometido:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in Z:\xampp\htdocs\restaurante-la-cena\connect2.php:48
Stack trace:
#0 Z:\xampp\htdocs\restaurante-la-cena\connect2.php(48): mysqli_fetch_array(false)
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>Z:\xampp\htdocs\restaurante-la-cena\connect2.php</b> on line <b>48</b><br />
```

El error que vi, probando cosillas que no entiendo, es que no hace la segunda conexión. Una vez definí la variable $aSql, al definir la variable $aRes, cambié la forma de hacerlo, y la puse así:

```
if(!$aRes = mysqli_query($conexion, $aSql)) die('No es posible');
```

Y sólo me imprime 'No es posible'. Si cambio la forma de definir dicha variable, me sale el error de arriba.
Lo demás asumo que lo tengo bien según la corrección del compañero @Triby. ¿Qué es lo que hice mal?

Comment: En tu consulta SQL tú puedes valerte de `GROUP_CONCAT`, de `CONCAT` y de `GROUP BY`  para construir la estructura que necesitas. Incluso, en versiones modernas de MySQL puedes guardar/obtener datos en forma de JSON con más simplicidad, pero eso depende de qué versión tengas y quizá de cómo tengas estructuradas las tablas. Por lo pronto, mientras te haces amigo de PHP, intenta concatenando y si tienes algún problema nos dices.

Comment: Oh, no me acordaba de lo de group, muchisimas gracias!! Lo probaré en cuanto pueda!

Comment: Por alguna razón quizás te ayude esto: `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); ` esto sería una cabecera para tu archivo php,  para especificar que lo que se mostrará será tipo JSON.

Comment: Pues Daniel, me ha ayudado muchísimo a ver la organización del mismo! muchas gracias! Ahora me queda que esté bien estructurado, probaré lo del amigo A. Cedano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero modifica la consulta para incluir la columna `id_plates`, es necesaria para obtener los alérgenos:

```
$sql = "SELECT category.name AS categoryname, plates.id_plates, plates.name AS platename, plates.specifications, plates.price
    FROM category
    JOIN plates
        ON category.id_category = plates.id_category
    WHERE category.allow = true AND plates.allow = true; ";
```

Crea el arreglo con índice por categoría, para poder agrupar los platos y, aunque podría no ser lo óptimo (a menos que haya platos que no contengan alérgenos), dentro del ciclo haces otra consulta para obtener los alérgenos:

```
// Inicializar el arreglo
$menu = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $category = $row["categoryname"];
    $plate = $row["platename"];
    $specification = $row["specifications"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    // Verificar si la categoría ya está creada
    if(!isset($menu[$category])) {
        // No existe, crear arreglo vacío
        $menu[$category] = [
            'category' => $category,
            'content' => []
        ];
    }
    // Obtener alérgenos
    $aSql = "SELECT p.id_allergen, a.name, a.description
        FROM plates_allergen p
        JOIN allergen a
            ON p.id_allergen = a.id_allergen
        WHERE p.id_plates = {$row['id_plates']}";
    $aRes = mysqli_query($conexion, $aSql);

    // Crea un arreglo para los alérgenos
    $allergen = [];
    while($aRow = mysqli_fetch_array($aRes)) {
        // Inserta cada alérgeno, con nombre y descripción
        $allergen[] = $aRow['name'] . " - " . $aRow['description'];
    }

    // Insertar plato
    $menu[$category]['content'][] = [
        'plate' => $plate,
        'specification' => $specification,
        'price' => $price,
        'allergen' => $allergen
    ];
}
```

Al final, para evitar que cada categoría sea una propiedad del JSON resultante, usas los [valores del arreglo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php):

```
$json_string = json_encode(array_values($menu), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Aclaración:** Creo que podrías obtener un objeto final más manejable si usas las categorías como propiedades y evitas `content`, quedando algo como:

```
{
    // Cada categoría es una propiedad con arreglo de platos
    "categoria 1": [
        // Cada plato es un objeto dentro del arreglo
        {
            "plate": "plato 1",
            "price": "8",
            "allergen": [
                "alergeno 1",
                "alergeno 2",
                "alergeno 3"
            ]
        }, // Más platos de la misma categoría
    ],
    "categoría 2": [ ... ]
}
```

Si te gusta la idea, solo hay que hacer algunos cambios:

```
    // Verificar si la categoría ya está creada
    if(!isset($menu[$category])) {
        // No existe, crear arreglo vacío
        $menu[$category] = [];
    }
    // ... consulta de alérgenos ...
    // Insertar plato
    $menu[$category][] = [
        'plate' => $plate,
        'specification' => $specification,
        'price' => $price,
        'allergen' => $allergen
    ];
```

Al final, creas el JSON normalmente:

```
$json_string = json_encode($menu, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: ufff, tengo que probar esa maravilla. Pero si, en principio, muchos platos no tienen alérgenos. Pero da igual, en cuanto pueda pruebo esto!!!

Comment: Me genera un pequeño error: (Uncaught Error: Undefined constant &quot;id_plates&quot). ¿No está definida la constante id_plates?

Comment: @AQMR, cierto, faltaba encerrar entre comillas `id_plates` en la consulta para obtener los alérgenos. Actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: En cuanto pueda edito la pregunta porque me saltan más errores que no comprendo ahora mismo

Comment: Ya está resuelto!!! Tuve que trastear en un momento de lucidez máxima. Tuve que quitar el 'true' final de la variable $aSql. En fin, resuelto! Muchísimas gracias por vuestra ayuda!!!

Comment: @AQMR, me alegro que lo hayas podido resolver y, sí, ya me di cuenta del error en la consulta... se quedó al copiar de la original.